# Cisco/Juniper IOS hacking?

Tags: encryption, cisco, cisco-ios, juniper, junos

I am a University student and I'm currently working on a paper of ethical hacking.

I have already investigated a lot about Web based attacks(SQLI, XSS, etc.) and about two months ago I started learning more about RE (Reverse Engineering) in Immunitydebugger.

My professor (who is a CCNP and is an instructor of CCNA) was telling me that I should look if it is possible to break into a Cisco or Juniper operating system but I have no idea where to start.

I already found the links below but the securitytube video is quite old and I don't think it will still work. The last video (NSA) was intriguing me most but they do not describe this technically.

Here are the links to the two videos I described above:

- http://www.securitytube.net/video/266
- http://gigaom.com/2013/12/29/nsas-backdoor-catalog-exposed-targets-include-juniper-cisco-samsung-and-huawei/

Does anyone know of a knowledge base or information related to breaking into a Cisco or Juniper router that would be beneficial for me?

Comment: There's a lot of material on this on-line, and it's safe to say it's not a trivial task. I'd recommend that you start with looking up Felix 'FX' Lindner pages like http://www.phenoelit.org/stuff/papers.html have some good references to starting with that kind of stuff...